# Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, ejs

I'm trying to incorporate google maps on a website that I am developing and need help with the below thing. I tried resolving it in multiple ways, but couldn't . I am working on node.js and data from back end mongodb is being rendered to the front end as " data " which has the coordinates that i need . I am trying to add the markers dynamically by using a for loop and that's where I'm having issue . Any help would be appreciated .
This is the first time I am asking a question here. So please excuse me in case there is a lack of information or errors.

mongodb query within my route :

```
app.get("/searchResult5",function(req, res) {
  var userInput1=req.query.column1;
  var userInput2=req.query.column2;
  var userInput3=req.query.column3;
  if(userInput1 ==="Column1"  ){    
    dataset5.find().sort({State : 'asc'}).exec(function(err,alldata){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        //console.log(alldata);
        res.render("results/searchResult5",{data:alldata,});
      }
    });

  }   
}
// code for the map inside an ejs template//
function initMap() 
{
  var center = {lat: 37.0902, lng: -95.7129};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: center
  });

  function addMarker(coords){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: coords,
      map: map,
    });
  }  
  for( var i=0; var i< <%=data.length%> ; i++){
    addMarker({lat:<%=data[i].lat%>,lng:<%=data[i].long%>});
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
object output via console.log

1) console.log(<%=data%>)

2) console.log(<%=data[0]%>)
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjs1o.png)

[data output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuxYj.png)

Comment: where is that template coming from?

Comment: You'll need to also post your code with the query of the mongodb and the render function for the EJS page. I have a suspicion the issue is that your query is returning an array-like object, not an array, and you need to explicitly make it an array first.

Comment: @DanielA.White : made the changes

Comment: @ecg8 : hopefully this makes it easier . again sorry for the inconsistent data , as I said , its my first time ever here posting a question

Comment: Do me a favor. Just above the line "res.render("results/searchResult5",{data:alldata,});", add the line "alldata = Array.from(alldata);" and see what happens.

Comment: no change , still the same . Data is being passed as [{data}]

Comment: Just want to ask, in which part of the code did you include those console.log? can you try using the console.log(<%=data[i]%>) above the addMarker inside the loop?

Comment: I feel like you are not passing the data properly in the function.